# do you have to declare null function params arduino?

Tags: arduino

In php you can do the following:

```
someFunction($var1, $var2);

function someFunction ($var1, $var2, $var3 = null) {

}
```

Does a similar construct exist in arduino where I can leave out a param and the default for it will be as defined in the function param list? Because I've found if I don't declare $var3 in the call I get an error that it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something similar with Arduino as well.
The C-like language used in Arduino supports C++ style default values for parameters.

So you could do something like this:

```
int test( int a, int b = 1 ) {
  return a * b;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin( 9600 );
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println( test( 10, 5 ) );  // Returns 10 * 5 = 50
  Serial.println( test( 5 ) );      // Returns 5 * 1 = 5

  delay( 10000 );
}
```

As in C++, all parameters with default values will have to come after any parameters without defaults.

Comment: Arduino is C++.